# Having trouble with intial migration to database

Tags: c#, .net, database, dbcontext

I created my SQL server and I can log in to it fine with those credentials in management studio. Excuse me if i said anything that doesnt make sense im new to this topic and this is my first stack overflow post thank you.

Context

```
    public class CommanderContext : DbContext
    {
        public CommanderContext(DbContextOptions<CommanderContext> opt) : base(opt)
        {

            
        }
        public DbSet<Command> Commands { get; set; }

    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings":
  {
    "CommanderConnection":"DESKTOP-M1BQ0T1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CommanderDB;User ID=CommanderAPI;Password=123;"

  }
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CommanderContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer
                (Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommanderConnection")));
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddScoped<ICommanderRepo, MockCommanderRepo>();


        }
```

Im trying to follow allong a youtube tutorial. When I run

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

I get

> Build started...
> Build succeeded.
> Unable to create an object of type 'CommanderContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that your `Program.cs` like below,

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```